# How i can get internationalized date string from Zend_Date without time

Tags: zend-framework, zend-date

I need to echo internationalized time in different format for different languages.
Now i am using locale when creating a date, but it also outputs time:

```
$date->toString();
29.05.2012 0:00:00
```

Expected result:

```
29.05.2012
```

In documentation i can see inly custom formats (as i understand no internationalization format will be applied if i use them). Is it possible to output only date, without time, like described there (as i understand zf supports international formats: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)?

I tried:

```
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT, $locale);
echo $date->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT); ?>
// produces  MMMMMMMM (letters instead of date? Oo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because it was necessary to add

```
Zend_Date::setOptions(array('format_type' => 'iso'));
```

in bootstrap instead of

```
Zend_Date::setOptions(array('format_type' => 'php'));
```

With this option, it works fine!